# Oracle SQL - SELECT with Variable arguments stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, parameter-passing

I'm struggling with a **variable argument** stored procedure that has to perform a SELECT on a table using every argument passed to it in its WHERE clause.

Basically I have **N account numbers** as parameter and I want to return a table with the result of selecting three fields for each account number.

This is what I've done so far:

```
function sp_get_minutes_expiration_default(retval IN OUT char, gc IN OUT GenericCursor,
        p_account_num IN CLIENT_ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NUM%TYPE) return number
        is
    r_cod integer := 0;
    begin
        open gc for select account_num, concept_def, minutes_expiration_def from CLIENT_ACCOUNTS
            where p_account_num = account_num;  -- MAYBE A FOR LOOP HERE?
        return r_cod;
    exception

        -- EXCEPTION HANDLING

    end sp_get_minutes_expiration_default;
```

My brute force solution would be to maybe loop over a list of account numbers, select and maybe do a UNION or append to the result table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast your input parameter as a table, then you can join it to CLIENT_ACCOUNTS

```
select account_num, concept_def, minutes_expiration_def
from CLIENT_ACCOUNTS ca, table(p_account_num) a
where a.account_num = ca.account_num
```

But I would recommend you select the output into another collection that is the output of the function (or procedure). I would urge you to not use reference cursors.

ADDENDUM 1

A more complete example follows:

```
create or replace type id_type_array as table of number;
/

declare
   ti id_type_array := id_type_array();
   n number;
begin
   ti.extend();
   ti(1) := 42;
   select column_value into n from table(ti) where rownum = 1;
end;
/
```

In your code, you would need to use the framework's API to:

1. create an instance of the collection (of type id_type_array)
2. populate the collection with the list of numbers
3. Execute the anonymous PL/SQL block, binding in the collection

But you should immediately see that you don't have to put the query into an anonymous PL/SQL block to execute it (even though *many* experienced Oracle developers advocate it). You can execute the query just like any other query so long as you bind the correct parameter:

```
select account_num, concept_def, minutes_expiration_def
from CLIENT_ACCOUNTS ca, table(:p_account_num) a
where a.column_value = ca.account_num
```

Comment: @jeff5times7 In this short example p_account_num should be of what type, a SQL LIST?? I've been reading about the TABLE() function but I don't really understand what argument it takes. Could you expand a little further please?

Comment: Please see ADDENDUM 1.